# RuntimeWarning: Ignoring unimportable $PYTHONBREAKPOINT

Tags: python, breakpoints

I have a `breakpoint` in my script, but when the script hits the breakpoint, it outputs:

```
RuntimeWarning: Ignoring unimportable $PYTHONBREAKPOINT
```

Is this something that the package I'm using is stopping me from doing?

Comment: Please post the code you're working with, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This typically means that `ipdb` hasn't been installed if that's what you're using for the breakpoint.

Just run:

```
pip install ipdb
export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you run into this problem but also have `ipython` installed, you can make use of the `ipdb` that comes preinstalled with `ipython` in the `IPython.terminal.debugger` module. (I had a potentially specific use case where I was using an anaconda environment that didn't have `ipdb` installed, but did have `ipython`, and I was worried about messing around with it by installing `ipdb`.)

Specifically, you can set

> `export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=IPython.terminal.debugger.set_trace`

before running your script using `python -m pdb myscript.py`.

On my searches, I started with another `ipdb` debugger present in `IPython.core.debugger` (note that this one is `core` and not `terminal`). However, according to my own use and [this thread](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9612#issuecomment-225726469), that version is now 'plainer' and doesn't include fancy things like autocompletion. (I'm actually unclear on how the 'plain' version of `ipdb` differs from `pdb`.)

(A side note: I also found that the `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` variable affects how `breakpoint()` calls work even if a script is called using `ipython`. Which is to say, if you run a script with a `breakpoint()` using `ipython` with `pdb` on, when you hit that line you will fall into the debugger set by `PYTHONBREAKPOINT`, rather than `ipython`'s built in `ipdb`.)

Answer (score 0):

try using `pip install ipdb` and then `export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace`
hope it works for you